Troubleshooting SSL Connection Issues in PostgreSQL 14 with OpenSSL 3.2 and 3.3
I source-compiled OpenSSL version 3.3 and compiled PostgreSQL 14 with it. When I tried to enable encryption and authentication via SSL in PostgreSQL with ssl_mode=on, I encountered errors related to replication and server connection. However, everything works perfectly when SSL is disabled.
The error I received is as follows:
psql: error: connection to server at "<HostIP>", port 5433 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
SSL SYSCALL error: Connection reset by peer
connection to server at "<HostIP>", port 5433 failed: FATAL: no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted

I used the following command to connect:
psql -U <username> <dbname> -h <hostIP>
I configured PostgreSQL to run on port 5433. The connection works when using psql on the local server, but when I attempt to connect remotely, I encounter the above error.
In my pg_hba.conf file, all connections are defined as hostSSL with the md5 authentication method. The following configurations were added to postgresql.conf to enable SSL:
# SSL
ssl = on
ssl_ciphers = 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384'
ssl_ca_file = 'root.crt'
ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'
ssl_key_file = 'server.key'

To troubleshoot, I tried using OpenSSL version 3.2 but encountered the same issue. However, the setup works fine with OpenSSL versions lower than 3.2 using the same configurations. I'm unsure why it's not working with OpenSSL versions 3.2 and 3.3. Could you suggest some ideas to help me understand and resolve this issue?
I am using Debian 11.7 with kernel version 5.1 and PG Version: 14.3

Question needs more information. Add as update to question text 1) OS and version for server machine and remote machine. 2) Exact version of Postgres 14 include the x as in 14.x.

From https://openssl-library.org/news/openssl-3.2-notes/index.html  : The default SSL/TLS security level has been changed from 1 to 2.

@AdrianKlaver Added the machine configuration in the main question.

@clamp I am not sure how to implement this. I tried to change the ciphers but it is still using the default one.

It‘s a setting in openssl.conf - just a guess, but worth a try.

@clamp I reduced the security level to 1 from 2. But the issue is not resolved
